# In Microsoft Outlook, how do you make a rule to send an alert to another email address from a specific sender?

Tags: outlook

In Microsoft Outlook, I am looking for a rule that would send only an alert (no content nor subject of email) to a separate email address from a specific sender.

For example:

1. Email A1: Sends Email
2. Email B1: Receives Email
3. Email C1: Receives Alert

A1 sends an email to B1.

Once the email is received by B1, the Outlook rule sends an alert to C1 letting them know that the sender sent an email.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In Exchange/Exchange online create a transport rule that execute the following action: "Generate incident report and send it to..."

Comment: I understand how to create a rule and an alert; however, I don't understand how to do it for the scenario I am trying to complete.

Comment: Well, I believe I've suggested you a possible way to solve your problem. Please explain what exactly you do not understand?